# How to convert curl --use flag to use in postman

Tags: curl, postman

[image]

I have the following working curl request:

```
 $ curl -i --user a:b https://api.plivo.com/v1/Account/a/Message/
```

I want to convert it to be used in postman. From

```
https://gist.github.com/eneko/dc2d8edd9a4b25c5b0725dd123f98b10
```

I see

```
-u, --user USER[:PASSWORD]  Server user and password
```

How do you set the --user a:b parameters for this postman get request?

Comment: You could try the `Basic` Auth under the `Authorization` which would create a request header? I'm not familiar with that API so this would just be a guess..

Comment: Thanks that worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that's right, `--user` indicates username and password, however in the Postman, usually, authentication data passing with a header, thus you need to add user authentication to the header as following

```
curl -H 'Authorization: Basic MTIzOjEyMw==' \ https://api.plivo.com/v1/Account/a/Message/
```

Here `MTIzOjEyMw==` is a base64 string containing username and password in this format username:password

Here username and password is 123:123, change it with yours and create and give a try with Postman